# understanding the behaviour of unsigned numbers

Tags: c++, c, unsigned

My goal is have a sorted ascending list of unsigned int values, I use the `sub_func` to  choose which one is greater.

The `sub_func` return is `int` because I want to compare which one is greater for all the numbers it works fine but, I have a problem when I define the max value of unsigned int which is (`0xffffffff == -1`). I want to understand more on unsigned numbers over here. How would I solve this problem?

I have the following code:

```
#define p_max (0xffffffff)
uint32 a = p_max;
uint32 b = 20;

int sub_func(uint32 a, uint32 b) 
{
    return (b - a);
}
```

The retrun is 21, where as I want it to be 20 - MAX, which will be negative and my return type is negative.

But, i see it always a positive number. which I dont want, how to workaround this?

Comment: Why not go the standard way of returning `true` when `a < b` and `false` otherwise? Think of the situation when `a = b = max`, you need a wider, signed type e.g. C++11's `long long` which would be at least 64 bits.

Comment: I want the return value, its important for my further coding.

Comment: `unsigned` values can't be negative.

Comment: My return type is INT.

Comment: Hmmm and what's your plan when the difference between these two values is larger than `0x7fffffff`?

Comment: Read Variable section from this book https://breezeflutter.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/c_primer_5th_edition.pdf

Comment: what are you trying to do with the function sub_func()?

Comment: depending upon the return of sub_func I will decide whether to add in front or at the back of the list.

Comment: Are you sure you need the signed difference ? Don't you have enough with +/- or +1/0/-1 ?

Comment: addition/subtraction produces **one more bit**, so you can never get correct result in *every cases* without using a wider type. `return (int32_t)b - a;` will work for small differences between a and b but if they're far from each other, like `a = p_max; b = 0;` and vice versa it'll overflow

Answer (score 5):

(Assuming `uint32` is a 32 bit unsigned integral type).

`b - a` is an expression with type `uint32`since both operands are of that type. Due to the standards-defined *wrap-around* behaviour of `uint32`, it will have the value of 21.

You are assigning that to an `int` type, hence the return value.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't mix `int` and `uint`** unless it is really required as the max value is different because one bit will be used for sign.

Based on your latest comment, you can return 0 or 1 and then decide to add to tail/back or head/front.

```
uint32 sub_func(uint32 a, uint32 b)  
{
    if( a > b )
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

You can also use bool data type if you want to return true or false. Adjust your function return code based on the comparison and return data type.

Answer (score 1):

Frist, `signed` and `unsigned` of same type are stored in same a space of same size (for example `signed char` and `unsigned char` are stored on 1 byte). So, for `signed`, half of possible values are used to store positive values and the other part of possible values are used to store negative values. For `unsigned`, all possible values are for positive values only :

- `signed char` : -127 to 127
- `unsigned char` : 0 to 255

To calculate a negative, the most use solution is "two's complement". To store -1 :

- use of value of 1 : 0x01
- invert it : 0xFE
- add 1 : 0xFF

So, -1 is store in signed context as 255 in unsigned context.

It's for that every one say : **don't mix signed and unsigned!**

Or if you really need that, use a greater size to calculate signed and **be carefull**:

```
std::uint32_t a;
std::uint32_t b;

std::int64_t = static_cast<std::int64_t>(b) - static_cast<std::int64_t>(a)
```

Example with 8 and 16 bits size data : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38076c588de3907d

Comment: Don't you have the unsigned and signed char the wrong way round? Also, until C++14, signed char could be from -127 to +127.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is impossible.

```
20 - 0xfffffff = -4294967275
```

which is not representable by an int, restricted to the range `[-2147483648,2147483647]`.

The difference of two unsigned requires 33 bits !

Comment: So, if I declare p_max to be 0x0fffffff, will that work?

Comment: @Invictur It's a solution yes, to limit `unsigned` to max value of `signed`

Comment: Type `int` is not restricted to that range.

Comment: @2501: can you elaborate ?

Comment: @2501, please can you explain more on that and how that is gonna affect?

Answer (score 1):

The fact you are storing the result in an `int` does not prevent the subtraction being done using `unsigned` arithmetic.

A subtraction of two `uint32` always produces a result which is of type `uint32`.   If the mathematical result of the subtraction is negative, modulo arithmetic is used to produce a value between `0` and the maximum that the unsigned type can represent.

You have used that fact to get `0xFFFFFFFF` from `-1`.   It works equally with results of subtraction.

`20 - 0xfffffff` gives a value of `-4294967275`.   That modulo `0x100000000` (the maximum a `uint32` can represent, plus `1`) is `21` (`0x15`).  `21` converted to `int` is still `21`.

One way to produce a negative value is to avoid doing subtraction using `unsigned` variables, such as;

```
int sub_func(uint32 a, uint32 b) 
{
    return (a > b) ? 1 : ((a < b) ? -1 : 0));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this was frenglish :-)

Comment: That's the best answer in my opinion: the result comes from the fact that computers are not doing regular arithmetic, they are doing modulo arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

As the limit for a signed 32-bit int is [-2147483648,2147483647], it cannot hold the result of subtraction as it is out of the limit. You can go for a 64-bit data type to hold the result of subtraction. I tested the below code on Visual studio.

```
#define p_max 0xffffffff

unsigned int a = p_max;
unsigned int b = 20;

signed long long sub_func() 
{
    return ((signed long long)b - (signed long long)a);
}

int main()
{
    signed long long x = sub_func();
}
```

Comment: The return type is int.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, the question is why the **nResult** would be **21**.

```
#define p_max (0xffffffff)
uint32 a = p_max;
uint32 b = 20;

void main()
{
    int nResult = b - a;
}
```

You are trying to calculate:

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0100` - `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`

which is actually computed as adding

`1` (2's complement of `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`) to

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0100`.

= `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0101`

The result is 21 and there is no consideration of sign since it's produced by two uint32's operation. So it doesn't make any change even if you cast the result value to signed int, because it's already a positive value.

Answer (score -1):

I just tested this with VC2013 and the compiler is treating the values as signed integers, hence getting 21! Here's the disembly:-

```
int sub_func(uint32 a, uint32 b)
{
00B813C0  push        ebp
00B813C1  mov         ebp, esp
00B813C3  sub         esp, 0C0h
00B813C9  push        ebx
00B813CA  push        esi
00B813CB  push        edi
00B813CC  lea         edi, [ebp - 0C0h]
00B813D2  mov         ecx, 30h
00B813D7  mov         eax, 0CCCCCCCCh
00B813DC  rep stos    dword ptr es : [edi]
return (b - a);
00B813DE  mov         eax, dword ptr[b]
00B813E1  sub         eax, dword ptr[a]
}
00B813E4  pop         edi
00B813E5  pop         esi
00B813E6  pop         ebx
00B813E7  mov         esp, ebp
00B813E9  pop         ebp
00B813EA  ret
```

Comment: In what way would unsigned handling differ ??

Comment: I suppose it could support some form of underflow detection, or posibly a type conversion error (a possible narrowing conversion to int), I don't know the standard in detail about this, but it does explain why the result is 21 (20 - -1) instead of something with a large negative value (20 - p_max).

Comment: Not at all. There is no integer overflow/underflow in C, just undefined behavior (do you see any test on Carry or Overflow flag ?). Can you pinpoint a single instruction in that assembly that is signed or unsigned ??

Comment: Yes, I know all that, I'm just trying to explain the observed behaviour on an IA86 processor (other processors may vary). Doesn't the CPU always do unsigned integer addition and subtraction and it's only the interpretation of the result that defines the sign. It might be possible for the compiler to generate a warning about this or you could add an INTO instuction after the add/sub in an ASM block..

Comment: The point is that looking at that assembly code tells you absolutely nothing.

Comment: Tells you nothing? It tells you exactly what the CPU is doing surely? Admittedly it doesn't tell you the thought processes involved in creating the sequence of opcodes the compiler has created. Other compilers could create different sequences of opcodes.

Comment: Don't be bad faith. It tells you nothing about the signedness of the numbers, though you claim it.

Comment: Do i? "it's only the interpretation of the result that defines the sign" seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: "the compiler is treating the values as signed integers"